# why does _.escape modify / characters in Underscore.js?

Tags: underscore.js, html-escape

I was looking through the [Underscore.js api](http://underscorejs.org/#escape) and I noticed that `_.escape` escapes `&`, `<`, `>`, `"`, `'`, and `/` characters. What surprised me was escaping `/`.

Is there a reason to escape `/` characters that I don't know about?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**EDIT**: Alright, apparently, it is recommended by [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.231_-_HTML_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Element_Content) as it "helps end a HTML entity".

> Escape the following characters with HTML entity encoding to prevent
>   switching into any execution context, such as script, style, or event
>   handlers. Using hex entities is recommended in the spec. In addition
>   to the 5 characters significant in XML (&, <, >, ", '), the forward
>   slash is included as it helps to end an HTML entity.

```
& --> &amp;
< --> &lt;
> --> &gt;
" --> &quot;
' --> &#x27;     &apos; is not recommended
/ --> &#x2F;     forward slash is included as it helps end an HTML entity
```

Comment: It doesn't change `/` to `\/` it changes it to `&#x2F;`. Besides, `</script>` would be changed to `&lt;/script&gt;` which wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Updated the answer with the citation. I found it out myself just now.

Comment: and now that all makes sense :D

Answer (score 0):

A lot of time passed but I found same issue. The strange is that the list of changes on the code are according to [underscore github](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/modules/_escapeMap.js)

```
var escapeMap = {
  '&': '&amp;',
  '<': '&lt;',
  '>': '&gt;',
  '"': '&quot;',
  "'": '&#x27;',
  '`': '&#x60;'
};
```