# Using <% in Underscore.js templating without parsing it

Tags: templates, underscore.js

Usually, if you use templating by Underscore.js, any expression that looks like `<% ... %>` and `<%= ... %>` is parsed by Underscore.js

How do I escape such a value, in case I want to embed the text `<% ... %>` inside the template?

To put it in other words: How can I tell Underscore.js to ignore something that looks like a placeholder, but that isn't a placeholder?

I guess I have to use some kind of escaping, but the usual `\` won't work. If I type

```
_.template('<%= name %> ### \<%= name %>', { name: 'foo' });
```

I get `foo ### foo` as a result, which is obviously *not* what I wanted.

**Update:** To make more clear, what I want from the line above - it should result in

```
foo ### <%= name %>
```

Comment: precede with escape character????

Comment: And what *is* the escape character in this case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298274/why-does-escape-modify-characters-in-underscore-js

Comment: How do you feel about putting the `<%=...%>` in the value of `name` rather than the template? Is the final result going to be HTML?

Comment: Yes, the final result is going to be HTML. The point is that there *must* be any option to disable parsing. Otherwise it would not be possible to embed the string `<%= abc %>` as a string, without the need for another variable.

Comment: @madhairsilence What exactly does the link you provided have in common with my question, except that it's both about escaping, but escaping in a completely different kind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your final output is going to be HTML, you could replace `<` and `>` with their HTML escape code thingers:

```
_.template('<%= name %> ### &lt;%= name %&gt;', { name: 'foo' });
```

You could also [modify Underscore's template settings](http://underscorejs.org/#template) to support these things, so that `<%= ... %>` means nothing to Underscore:

```
_.templateSettings = {
    interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};
var t = _.template('{{name}} ### <%= name %>', { name: 'foo' });
```

Answer (score 0):

For a non-html specific solution, use [unicode character escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Universal_character_names) to escape `<`, `>` and `%`. Using your example, this:

```
_.template('<%= name %> ### \u003C\u0025= name \u0025\u003E', { name: 'foo' });
```

Will output

```
foo ### <%= name %>
```